# Can I open terminator with one windows with bash and another with fish?

Tags: bash, fish, gnome-terminator

So I am running terminator 0.98. I like fish shell but for some task it is handy to have bash (like for virtualenvwrapper). So I now have two windows that open when I start terminator. But I would like to have one that opens with fish and one with bash. Is this possible, if so: how?

I start terminator with my custom layout by changing my config file located `~/.config/terminator/config`.

In the layout section of the config file I used this code.

```
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      fullscreen = False
      last_active_window = True
      maximised = True
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      size = 1280, 985
      type = Window
    [[[child1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      position = 490
      ratio = 0.5
      type = VPaned
```

Comment: Just start the alternative shell manually. e.g. `$ bash`

Comment: How do you start those terminators? I don't know terminator, but it probably has an option to specify what command to run, so call it (edit the menus to give an extra option, or whatever suits your way or working) with that option. E.g. I prefer the old xterm so I have a script doing `xterm -e screen` to get a terminal where screen is running (the script does more than that, but that's not important).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `command` to the relevant pane. If your default shell is `bash`, just have one pane run `fish`:

```
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      fullscreen = False
      last_active_window = True
      maximised = True
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      size = 1280, 985
      type = Window

    [[[child1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      command = 'bash'
      position = 490
      ratio = 0.5
      type = VPaned
    [[[child1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      position = 490
      ratio = 0.5
      type = VPaned
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry I hadn't found the other post while googling.

Comment: @TristanT no worries, finding duplicates is often hard.